# provider discovery url in windows live id

Tags: openid, windows-live-id

Microsoft has announce that [WindowsLiveID become a OpenID provider](http://winliveid.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!AEE1BB0D86E23AAC!1791.entry). I want implement it in my application but I can't find the provider discovery URL.

In blog post they call about live.com but it's doesn't works.

Anyone know this provider discovery URL ?

Comment: I thought it's been essentially offline since the CTP ended around August '09.

Comment: So you can't logged by OpenID system with WindowsLiveID ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very post you link to includes the answer: Windows LiveID is not an OpenID Provider.  They did have a limited CTP going, which was not on Windows LiveID itself but on a test-only clone, but it's now down.

I believe Microsoft has promised that they'll be an OpenID Provider someday.  But no timeline has been given.